# validating MON-YY format in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, format, validation

How to validate that whether the input is in correct format? I need to check format like JUN-12. i.e. MON-YY format. This field is of string type in Model.

How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

If you validate model you can use `RegularExpressionAttribute`.

If you validate in Controller you can use pure Regular expression.

Comment: but regular Expression will allow DDD-12 also.. or will exactly validate month short form only? So i need to check that also.